# react-native run siri shortcut without opening the app

Tags: ios, react-native, shift, siri, sirishortcuts

I am using "react-native-siri-shortcut' library to make shortcuts.

`suggestedInvocationPhrase` for my shortcut is *"It's Tea Time"* so when the user says **"Hey Siri, It's Tea Time"** then Siri opens the app and gives the whole shortcut object via `addShortcutListener`, but this listener only works when the app is in foreground or background.

This listener is not working when the app is completely closed.

So now what I want is to make an one shortcut that work's without opening the app. I just want to call a single API whenever the user say **"Hey Siri, It's Tea Time"** and once the API called Siri have to say back "Your order was placed successfully..." (I want all this process without opening the app).

here are some reference:

https://medium.com/simform-engineering/how-to-integrate-siri-shortcuts-and-design-custom-intents-tutorial-e53285b550cf

https://github.com/Gustash/react-native-siri-shortcut/issues/87

Comment: I am looking for the answers also.